# CSS Transitions only working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, animation

I have created a menu where when you hover over the link the title slides left out of the frame, and different words slide in (client request). I am trying to do this in CSS only, and it works exactly as expected in Chrome, but not in Firefox or Opera. Only the second animation (where the different words slide in) works, but the primary animation (where the normal word slides out) does not have its transition applied. Here is a jsFiddle with an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3tUAN/

I can resort to using jQuery if I must (the code is there, already needed for IE9) but I would like to get this working for CSS-only if possible. I have considered trying to get more specific with selectors (using the child selector, something like `a.MenuLink > li.MenuItem > span.MenuTitle`) but I was hoping the community could help me on this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify an initial value for `left` for the `span.MenuTitle`. This may be a bug in the other browsers, but it fixes it in Firefox. Something like this:

```
span.MenuTitle {
    left: 0;
}
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3tUAN/1/)

Comment: bloody hell, I totally missed that. I know Firefox and Opera are more explicit and require declaration of both X and Y locations, it just totally slipped my mind. thank u, in 8 minutes I can check mark it.